# ARC fault breaker trips won’t stay on. Then does without a fix to wires

Tags: electrical

A flying squirrel entered finished attic. When light switch was switched on, ARC fault circuit blew. It kept blowing, would not stay on. Assumed squirrel had chewed wires. They do that. When each leg of wires was tested to find the damaged leg in need of rewriting, all legs worked without blowing ARC fault breaker. Power leg on its own worked, and the wires between the three way switches did not trip the ARC fault breaker, and then the switch leg wire to the lights from both switches that light up two sets of ceiling lights all worked without tripping the ARC fault breaker.  And the lights are back on working with no ARC fault breaker interruption. What could explain this situation? Can the integrity of the system be trusted?  Should a new ARC fault breaker be tried?

Comment: What else is on that circuit, any vents or fans?

Comment: Just lights. 9 lights across three tracks on two 3 way switches. And lights in the storage space in the eves which are rarely used and can be in now with the tracked lighting no problem.  The home owner says the breaker blew when he turned on lighters to see what the noise was in middle of night. He said it would not stay on when reset. It has been off for 6 weeks. Today everything is working fine.

Comment: I'd be suspicious of it.  It's possible that your resetting of the breaker, and I assume you did it more than once, caused the fault to resolve itself.  But that problem still exists and is a danger.  I'd run the wires on the affected circuit until I found the problem and then fix it.

Comment: I agree. The problem, assumed to be caused by little flying squirrel teeth somewhere on the circuit, could have been minor enough to have “fussed” itself together enough to stop the arch fault enough to not trip the breaker. But the damage is still there. The difficulty is not knowing which wire is damaged. Thank You for your response.